# No resource found that matche the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat

I'm facing few problems related to the theme.

In my manifest, I have the following code:

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

By using the above code, there is error `No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'`. Please refer to the image below that I've added the reference.

If I remove the theme setting, I'll receive runtime error saying that I must implement AppCompat theme. May I know which part has gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: have you referenced appcompact v7 library in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you have referenced appcompat v7 library in your project, my initial guess is that you should use

```
<application
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

instead of

```
<application
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Also ensure that both Android Support Library project and the Main Project have the same `minSdkVerson` and `targetSdkVersion`.

The key thing here i guess is that in the parent attribute `android:`.It prefixes built in themes (styles), while a value without this prefix references your own styles or the styles in any libraries you have linked to, in this case `android-support-v7-appcompat`.